AD8400 Digipot: Non linearity in output resistance in rheostat mode
I am controlling the AD8400(1 kohm) digipot with Arduino Uno R3 using SPI interface. My connections are as follows:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Digipot <-> Arduino
CS(3) <->10
SDI(4) <-> 11
CLG(5) <->13
VDD(6) <-> 5v
I am checking the resistance across terminal W and B using multimeter after giving input between 0 to 255.But the resistance obtained is not varying linearly and it also exceeds the Resistor Nonlinearity((-4) -(+4) LSB) provided in datasheet.
Below is the graph obtained for values between 0-255

Blue line indicates the observed values
Red line is for the equation:
Resistance = 43.2 + (Data/ 255) * (1000)
(Since I got 43.2 on giving 0 as data I have assumed it as wiper resistance)
These are some of the resistance readings obtained


Below is the code used:
#include <SPI.h> // include the SPI library





#define slaveSelectPin 10 // set pin 10 as the slave select for the digital pot

int address = 0; //addr bits = 0)

int value = 72; // value can be anything between 0 to 255





void setup() {

  pinMode(slaveSelectPin, OUTPUT);// set the slaveSelectPin as an output:

  Serial.begin(115200);  

  SPI.begin(); // initialize SPI:

}





void DigitalPotWrite(int addr, int val){

  digitalWrite(slaveSelectPin, LOW);

  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(10000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1)); //initialises SPI clock speed, mode and bit order

  digitalWrite(slaveSelectPin, LOW);

  SPI.transfer(addr);

  SPI.transfer(val);

  digitalWrite(slaveSelectPin, HIGH);

  SPI.endTransaction(); 

}







void loop() {

  digitalWrite(slaveSelectPin, HIGH); // ensure default CS stays high for now

  DigitalPotWrite(address, value);

  

  delay(5000); //abitrary delay 

}


Can someone please check what could be the error and how to reduce it?

Your value seems to increase with your control so the sw seems to work. Did you connect the analog ground? And how do you measure the resistance, your voltage applied by the DMM should be within the supply.

"I am checking the resistance across terminal W and B using multimeter. " Are the terminals W/B and the multimeter floating? The datasheet shows how to measure nonlinearity in rheostat mode.

This is an electrical/electronic design site and that means, on this particular occasion, you need to supply an exact schematic of your test set-up. Writing what connections you made is unacceptable. There is a schematic editor that you can use when you edit your question.

@janh i can assure that the mutimeter is giving accurate readings

@Raonoke I didnt quite understand what you are saying... they have given the block diagram on page 21 of the datasheet :
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8400_8402_8403.pdf

@AvantikaNarvekar - You didn't show yet how the multimeter is connected. Is terminal B of the digipot connected to GND? Take a look at fig. 38 in the datasheet.

Edit the question to add a photo (or several) of how you have connected it all on the breadboard, so that we can follow all the wires between arduino and the potentiometer, and between the potentiometer and the multimeter. You really should draw a schematic of how it's all connected, not just use textual descriptions. In EE, a single schematic can replace many pages of descriptive text.

There's no way to have images in comments, nor to have more extensive comments needed to guide you with what's expected of a question, so I'll have to use a part of this answer instead.
The schematic editor is built into this site. When editing the question, position the cursor on a line where you'd want the schematic to appear, and click the button highlighted in red below:

Firmware
You must always read-back the value from the potentiometer to confirm that it is exactly what you wrote to it. Otherwise, the writing/reading code is just plain incorrect, the wiring between the Uno and the pot is wrong, or the pot is faulty (least likely I'd hope).
Before you get this read-back working, you should not even attempt to measure any resistances, since you have no idea what you actually set the potentiometer to - as opposed to what you wish/imagined it got set to, which is likely to be wrong!
Ohmmeter Connection
Here's what we'd like to see on the schematic you'd post. Make sure that your circuit matches your schematic!

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It is very important that you connect the COM/(-) terminal of the ohmmeter to a grounded pin on the resistor. One of the A1, B1, W1 pins on the resistor has to be connected to GND for the measurement with the ohmmeter to work, and it must be the same pin that connects to the ohmmeter's COM/(-) terminal. If the GND connection is missing, you won't get correct results - exactly as you have noted.
Alternatively, the OHMS/(+) terminal of the ohmmeter can be connected to potentiometer's VCC:

simulate this circuit
The incorrect resistance reading, if you don't do it this way, is because there will be no defined potential relative to ground (and by extension VCC) established on the potentiometer pins (A/B/W). The potential on those pins will only be established by the ESD diodes. Thus, the ohmmeter will be measuring as-if there was a diode in series with it, and/or the internal switching matrix won't have the resistance as low as it normally would have. Thus all the measurements are expected to be higher - and that's what you got. Without the ground connection, the actual circuit is like below:

simulate this circuit
Due to details of how the potentiometer is constructed, when connected the way you presumably did it, the resistance will appear as-if it was connected to ground, not to the B1 pin. This happens because the ohmmeter is sourcing current from the B1 pin, and drives it slightly negative relative to GND since there is nothing external to limit the voltages to stay between GND and VCC.
This negative (relative to GND) potential on B1 causes changes in the behavior of the switching matrix that implements the "digital wiper" of the digital potentiometer.
You may also get different "weird" behavior if you switch the ohmmeter polarity in this case.
There's a bit of complexity to why exactly this all happens, but the simple answer is: if you measure the voltages on the A,B,W pins using a high impedance voltmeter (10MΩ RIN or higher) while the ohmmeter is connected, you will find that at least one of the pins is outside of the recommended operating voltage range. This won't happen anymore once the COM ohmmeter terminal is connected to circuit GND.
If the voltmeter impedance is too low, you may find that just connecting the voltmeter to measure A/B/W voltage relative to GND "fixes" the resistance measurements. This is obviously not what you want.
When connected as in the first picture, the polarity of the ohmmeter won't matter, as long as whatever AD8400 pin the COM/(-) is connected to, is also connected to GND, or alternatively, the pin for OHMS/(+) is connected to VCC.

This is why having a schematic of how you measured things was important. The problem would have been then immediately obvious without any guesswork as to what you may have done wrong. Absent a full schematic, I was forced to guess. So this answer may not reflect your situation. This is EE as someone said, and schematics are the means of communication. By not having a schematic representing your actual setup, you made it harder for us to help you :)

they have given the block diagram on page 21 of the datasheet

They did, sure. But the datasheet doesn't show what you did. Sometimes you may think you did what the datasheet said, but if you take the time to follow all the wiring in your real circuit, you'll find that there was a mistake of some sort.
So, in a way, showing the actual schematic of what you put together helps you find your own mistakes. The schematic should be "reverse engineered" by following the connections - don't just assume that the connections you have agree with what you had in mind.
And note that here "you" really applies to anyone, me included. I sometimes have a schematic that looks correct but the circuit doesn't work. Then I trace the circuit to draw a second schematic based on what I built... And it turns out the first and second schematics are different. It's a surprisingly easy kind of a mistake to make!

Sorry for the late update. Thank you so much everyone for trying to guide me. I actually got the solution to my issue. The issue was just in a line in my code. I had written:
SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(10000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));

in the function DigitalPotWrite()
.... I just had to change SPI_MODE1 to SPI_MODE0 since data is sampled on rising edge clock in mode 0. Now the graph obtained is quite linear and deviation obtained is within the limits mentioned in datasheet.

Also, thank you @Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica for trying to solve this issue. But since I have clearly mentioned that I am checking the output in rheostat mode I dont have to connect Vdd and Gnd to A and B terminals respectively. I believe this is the closest I can make to show the entire circuit connections.


A floating digipot and multimeter is not the way to do the test in rheostat mode. Take a moment to think about how the switches inside the digipot work and why the pot has to be connected for testing as shown in the datasheet.
